# Guys in vs-code how can i run any command on existing terminal without adding new terminal what shortcut-key i can use here?

Tags: reactjs, cmd, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code sometime there is no way to run any command on existing terminal.
So how can i run any command on existing terminal without adding new terminal.
Is there any short-cut key i can use to run any command?

Answer (score -1):

CTRL +  SHIFT  +  P

Its the shortcut to run any command in VS Code